# Prove that given any $0<t<1$, $f(x)=\sin(x) - tx$ has a solution in $(0,\pi)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $0<t<1$ has been given to us. Prove that $f(x) = \sin(x) - tx$ has a solution in $(0,\pi)$

I proposed this statement when I was trying to answer one of the questions on MSE. I tried to prove it using the Intermediate Value Theorem and Banach's fixed point theorem. It turned out that both approaches became very similar to each other.

I have already proven that this is true. So, I'm just proposing it as a fun calculus/analysis question on MSE because it wasn't asked before and it's a more or less difficult question compared to how innocent it looks.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: With non-zero solution, you mean that $f(x)$ has a zero in $(0,\pi)?$

Comment: @gammatester yeah xD saying it's non-zero was redundant, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With heavier machinery.

Let $f(x)=\sin x-tx$ on $[0,\pi]$. Then $f'(x)=\cos x-t$ only vanishes once and $f''(x)=-\sin x$ is negative over $(0,\pi)$. Thus $f$ has a maximum in $(0,\pi)$, which is positive because $f(0)=0$. Since $f(\pi)=-t\pi<0$, there is a single root for $f(x)=0$ in the interval $(\arccos t,\pi)$.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An equivalent statement is that $\operatorname{sinc}x:=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ (defined as $1$ at $x=0$ by continuity) achieves every value $\in (0,\,1)$ for some $x\in (0,\,\pi)$. It suffices by continuity to note $\operatorname{sinc}0=1,\,\operatorname{sinc}\pi=0$.